# App won't transfer from iTunes to iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes

We have a working app and we want to field test it by putting on our client's iPhone. We've already put the app onto one of our phones through iTunes with no problems. When we tried to get it onto the other phone (after getting it onto iTunes) there was an error.
The other computer already has the provisioning profile on iTunes, both phones are included in the profile, both phones are the same model (4s) and are running the same OS.
The only difference I can think of is that we are trying to transfer through a PC for this one, whereas we used a Mac. I hope this isn't the problem.
Is there any way to know what's causing the problem? Or a workaround?

Comment: It would help of you explained what happens when you try to install on the other phone. Also post the actual error message you are getting. Is this all being done through standard Adhoc distribution?

Comment: try using iPhone Configuration Utility....

Comment: When we try to sync it iTunes does not finish syncing, then the phone says "[App name] failed to install" or something like that. Also we are dealing with all of this remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try testflight or diawi for installation of app. its very easy.

Comment: Better question after looking at them: is diawi secure?

Comment: Yes Diawi is secure. I am using it from last 4 years. 
you can also try testflight it has a lot of good functionality and much secure

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting the device under "Organizer" and choosing "Use for development"?

Comment: We aren't installing it to the phone through a mac, so I don't think we can do that.